# How to force a CONFIG_ option to stay on?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, configuration

I don't know how to properly debug the kernel configuration process when an option that should be on ( because it doesn't really depends on anything and it doesn't conflict with anything that I can think of ) , really can't find a way to live beyond `make olddefconfig` .

Among other things I'm using

```
CONFIG_SYS_SUPPORTS_ZBOOT=y
```

with a `4.8.6` kernel tree and I found no way to write a `.config` file that will retain this specific flag on after using `make` and according to the available documentation and scripts in the `arch/mips` this shouldn't happen .

Since this option is required in order to generate `vmlinuz` for mips targets I have enabled lzma for the kernel for both compression and decompression but so far ... nothing, `CONFIG_SYS_SUPPORTS_ZBOOT=y` keeps on "going off" .

Do you have any idea how I can literally force a CONFIG flag to stay on or how to debug why `make` and `kbuild` are thinking that this flag can't be on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually changing the .config file without Kconfig is discouraged as it might lead to unexpected behavior. In your case the best solution would be to run

```
make menuconfig
```

and selecting the configuration option from the menuconfig (the parameter you are looking for should be under arch/mips).

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

`SYS_SUPPORTS_ZBOOT` doesn't have any prompt so it is not user selectable.

That option is supposed to be selected by your platform (`Machine selection`, `System type` choice). If this is not the case, it probably mean that this is not supported by your machine.